# else: not working in jupyter notebook python 3

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm running some basic commands in Jupyter Notebook(via python 3), and my they aren't running properly. In the code if I set A to equal 1, the IF statement works fine but if I set it higher than b the else statement doesn't do anything. it simply prints test without the else string i wrote. I'm very new to coding, so I apologize for any incorrect terminology. I used proper spacing for the if-else statements as well(4 spaces) [Here is my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zbKB.png)

edit: I did find an alternative code that functions properly but I'm still confused as to why the first doesn't work, [here is the alternative.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsrif.png)

edit 2: it has come to my attention that I should have posted the code in text, so Ill post the first one(the problem):

```
a = 5
b = 2
if a < b:
    print("a is less than b")
else:
    print:("a is NOT less than b")
print ("test")
```

Comment: Please report the code as text instead of using an image.

Comment: @norok2 I think he is new here and doesn't know the policy yet

Comment: Have you tried it in an online editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you have a colon after your print word in the else statment. change

`print:("a is NOT less than b")`

to

`print("a is NOT less than b")`